# Difficulty Displaying "undefined" for Empty Array Indices Using forEach Loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a JavaScript project involving arrays and forEach loops, and I'm facing an issue that I can't seem to resolve. I want to display the contents of an array with a twist: I'd like to show the string "undefined" for any empty indices in the array. However, despite trying various approaches, I still can't achieve the desired result.

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
const fruits = ["banana", "apple", "watermelom", "grapes"];
  fruits[7] = "Lemon";

  let text = "<ul>";

  fruits.forEach(myFunction);

  text += "</ul>";

  function myFunction(value, index) {
    if (index in fruits) {
      text += "<li>" + value + "</li>";
    } else {
      text += "<li>undefined</li>";
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Unfortunately, this code isn't achieving the result I want, and I'm still not seeing "undefined" displayed for the empty indices. Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding about using the **forEach** loop in this context? Any insights or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: `forEach` skips `empty` entries.

Comment: …then don't use `.forEach`. Use a normal `for … of` loop

Comment: forEach executes myFunction for each array element. If there is no element (=undefined) it doesn't do anything. If you want to display undefined, you could use a for loop instead.

Comment: If you still want to use forEach, you can check if the value is empty `const textToDisplay = value == "" ? 'undefined' : value; text += "<li>" + textToDisplay + "</li>";`

Comment: @MaraBlack How do you expect that to work? `myFunction` isn't called at all for those elements.

Comment: It is, `fruits.forEach(myFunction);`, check in the function if the value is empty

Comment: @MaraBlack No, it doesn't. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/52v0mrbx/). (Elements 4, 5 and 6 are skipped.)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j1mog04f/2/

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right

Comment: @Emilien `undefined` is a valid array entry, and `forEach` ___will___ iterate over it.

Comment: Hello everyone,

I'm still struggling to get the desired output using the provided solutions. Could someone please provide a complete code solution that would display "undefined" for the empty indices in the array when using the **forEach** loop? I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: @RexsaaGater Update function like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jagdish_j_p/0ocjmy72/3/

Comment: @RexsaaGater Remove the `.forEach()` call altogether and replace it with a regular `for` loop. https://jsfiddle.net/crobt2s7/

Comment: @ErJagdishPatel There is one too many `undefined`s in that list. And it also seems overly complicated.

Comment: @Ivar I also agree with your answer. That is short and simple.